# How to run nested loops in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following terraform map:

```
variable "methods" {
    type = map(object({
        # other fields
        response_model_map = map(string)
    }))
    description = "some description"
    nullable    = false
}
```

I need to loop the "methods" map to create multiple "aws_api_gateway_method" resources and also I need to access the "response_model_map" nested map in "methods" to create "aws_api_gateway_method_response" resources.

### Methods input

```
module "some-name" {
  source = "./modules/api-gateway-method"
  # other fields

  methods = {
    POST = {
      authorization    = "AWS_IAM"
      lambda_function  = module.some-lambda.lambda
      request_model    = aws_api_gateway_model.some.name
      response_error   = aws_api_gateway_model.response_message.name
      response_success = aws_api_gateway_model.some-response.name
      response_model_map = {
        200 : aws_api_gateway_model.some.name,
        400 : aws_api_gateway_model.response_message.name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Output

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "this" {
  for_each    = var.methods
  http_method = each.key
}
```

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {  
  # I need to use the http_method set for the "aws_api_gateway_method"
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.this.http_method
  status_code = response_model_map.key
  response_models = each.value.response_success != null ? {
    "application/json" = r response_model_map.value
  } : {}
}
```

I don't know how to loop a nested loop for creating "aws_api_gateway_method_response" resources.

Comment: What is the value of `var.methods`?

Comment: @Marcin I updated my question with the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your `var.methods`:

```
}

locals {

  methods_flat = merge([
    for method, options in var.methods: {
      for response_code, response_value in options.response_model_map: 
          "${method}-${response_code}" => {
              "method"         = method 
              "response_code"  = response_code
              "response_value" = response_value
              authorization    = options.authorization
              lambda_function  = options.lambda_function
              request_model    = options.request_model
              response_error   = options.response_error
              response_success = options.response_success
          }
     }  
  ]...) # dots are important. do NOT remove.

}
```

then

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {  
  
  for_each = local.methods_flat
  
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.this[each.value.method].http_method
  status_code = each.value.response_code
  response_models = each.value.response_success != null ? {
    "application/json" = each.value.response_value
  } : {}
}
```